# How to position and style blockquote in css

Tags: html, css

Hi guys! I require some CSS help styling my blockquote rule. My desired result is to have the opening quote above the quoted text, and the closing quote below the quoted text.

This image illustrates exactly what I require - [site design](http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/mrtest/student-i-info-v1.jpg)

This is my current live WIP link - [Live link](http://www.garyrevell.co.uk/mrtest/page-standard.html)

**My CSS:**

```
blockquote {
color: #e33e00;
font-style: italic;
font-family: GeoSlb712XBdBT;
padding:20px;
padding-left: 15px;
border-left: 3px solid #F63;


}

blockquote p:before {
content: '"';
font-size: 30px;
top:20px;
position:absolute;

}

blockquote p:after {
content: '"';
font-size: 30px;
}
```

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures) in your questions.

Comment: Ok...still a newbie to stack overflow thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/mzQEP/1/)

Look at the code I added ( it's indented 4 spaces )

You need to add `position: relative;` to the `blockquote p` and then it was some absolute positioning on the `:before` and `:after` moving the `:before` up 15px and the `:after` down 30px.

resize the right side to make the quote grow and shrink and see that the quotes always stay on the top and bottom

and of course, you could do like 20px and 35px (or more) to add more space between the quotation marks and the `<p>` being quoted.

**EDIT:** Added the code below, additional code to fix the issue is indented 8 spaces

```
blockquote {
    color: #e33e00;
    font-style: italic;
    font-family: GeoSlb712XBdBT;
    padding:20px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-left: 3px solid #F63;
}


        blockquote p { position: relative; }

blockquote p:before {
content: '"';
font-size: 30px;
position:absolute;
        top:-15px;
        left:0px;
}

blockquote p:after {
content: '"';
font-size: 30px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-30px;
        left:0px;
}
```

​

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! hats off to you sir! :)

Comment: Glad to have been able to help! =)

Answer (score 0):

Like this http://www.visibilityinherit.com/code/css-blockquotes-how-to.php. Or use display inline block with the other. I tried to post code but can't indent correctly apparently.